# PHPStorm don't run search in background

Tags: phpstorm

I'm sorry to ask this here, but I've searched for a while with no results.  Can anyone tell me how, once having clicked "Background" on PHPStorm's search window, I can restore it to run regularly?  kinda driving me crazy here :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see background tasks (and be able to cancel it) check this [official manual page](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/working-with-background-tasks.html).

---

To make Search functionality not to run in background, do these steps:

- Close IDE completely
- Search for `ide.general.xml` file and open it in any text editor. For Windows 7 and PhpStorm v8 it would be `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde80\config\options\ide.general.xml`. For other OS check [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs).
- Look for `searchInBackground` text. e.g. `<option name="searchInBackground" ...`
- Either delete that node completely .. or change `value` to be `false` instead of `true`.
- Save changes made to this file and launch IDE.

Comment: of course I checked the manual page before posting, I didn't see it there. Thanks for the tip about the xml file!